# python send plotly chart (div) as email content

Tags: python, html, plotly

Im using plotly to create a chart and return div. I want to input div into the html  and send as an email.

```
div = plotly.offline.plot(data, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
```

here is the code:

```
 mail_msg = f'''
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">\n\t <font="Times New Roman"><font size="2">This Month：</font></p>
            <p>{table_predict_html}</p>
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">\n\t <font="Times New Roman"><font size="2">Contrast：</font></p>
            <p>{tot_html}</p>
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">\n\t <font="Times New Roman"><font size="2">Revenue：</font></p>
            <script src=“https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js”></script>
            <p>{div}</p>
            '''
 msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_msg, 'html', 'utf-8'))
```

table_predict_html and tot_html are tables in html. Tables displayed in the email but it's all blank for the chart. So what is the proper way of inserting the div to html?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript won't actually work in most mail clients. For HTML Mail you are better off sticking with basic HTML and images. MailChimp have a pretty good Write Up on the topic: [Link](https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/)

Comment: Yes，plotly has used javascript which is abandoned by most email providers for security reason

Answer (score 1):

If it is a static chart, you can save it as a picture file using 
`fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")` and send it as a picture.

If it is a dynamic chart, I think it probably will be easier if you do 

`div1 = div\
    .to_html()\
    .replace('<table border="1" class="dataframe">','<table class="table table-striped">')`

and then send it as an HTML.

Comment: but I get a blank email